# how to stop active thread stored in vector list having bufferreader and printwriter in it

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, bufferedreader, printwriter

Server.java

```
public synchronized static void logout(String str) throws IOException{

    Enumeration e = v1.elements();

    while(e.hasMoreElements()){
        Serverthread stm = (Serverthread)e.nextElement();
        stm.send(str);
    }

    Enumeration ex=names.elements();
    int indexOf = 0;
    while(ex.hasMoreElements()){
        String name=(String)ex.nextElement();
        String org = str.substring(1);
        if(name.equals(org)){
            indexOf= names.indexOf(name);
            names.removeElementAt(indexOf);
           System.out.println("names"+names.size());
            break;
        }
    }
    // Serverthread st=(Serverthread)v1.get(indexOf);

    Serverthread st=(Serverthread)v1.remove(indexOf);
    st.close();
    System.out.println(v1.size());
    System.out.println("connection closed..");
}
```

Comment: Where are your class attributes? Where is your Serverthread implementation? Where do you want to call start/stop?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the way to do this is to close the InputStream that the Thread is waiting on. If the Thread isn't waiting on anything, the only way to stop it is to call Thread.interrupt() and hope your Thread is checking to see if it has been interrupted